# Вывод лога в RichTextBox WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Задача: выводить лог сообщения в текстбокс в ходе работы приложения.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше всего это реализовать с использованием MVVM.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забиндить можно.

Xaml:

```
<RichTextBox Width="200" Height="100">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="{Binding Path=LineFormatted}" />
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

View-model:

```
private string lineFormatted;

public string LineFormatted
{
    get { return this.lineFormatted; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this.lineFormatted, value); }
}

public void WriteTextLine(string val)
{
    this.LineFormatted += $"[{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}]   {val}\r\n";
}
```

Где `LineFormatted` использует `INotifyPropertyChanged` так, как он у вас реализован (у меня это `SetProperty`).

Тест:

```
WriteTextLine("testing line");
```